# Is there an editor for Python programming that checks the code while writing?

Tags: linux, python

Is there an editor for novice programmer that checks the syntax while writing? I mean, I like to learn Python but as a beginner I make mistakes. I am looking something that it might for example underline the parts that violates PEP8 standard while writing the code in real time.

I'm using Linux Mint 18.3 Sylvia.

Answer (score 5):

## [IDE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integrated_development_environment)

I personally really like [PyCharm](https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/download/), it's an IDE for Python. It has plenty of options - from code completion, inspection, warnings on standards you can define, debugging etc.

There are two versions:

- Professional - Full-featured IDE for Python & Web development (free trial)/
- Community - Lightweight IDE for Python & Scientific development (free, open source).

I used to use the community and didn't had anything missing, and switched to the professional just because I could.

## [Text editor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Text_editor)

If you're more into a text editor, most of them will have plugins/extension for at least Basic python development.

- [Sublime Text](https://www.sublimetext.com/3)
- [VS Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/setup/linux)
- [Atom](https://atom.io/)
- [Vim](https://realpython.com/vim-and-python-a-match-made-in-heaven/)
- A lot more..

Comment: Well put! Of these, VS Code and Atom are probably easiest for a novice to get going, IMO

Answer (score 0):

PyCharm good, but too heavy for a beginner.
My choice Sublime text + [Anaconda (plugin)](http://damnwidget.github.io/anaconda/) + theme Ayu + some tunning.

Also i can recommend [Thonny](http://thonny.org/) - IDE for beginners

Comment: Geany is also a nice editor that is really a lightweight IDE. It understands Python, has an optional terminal window, and configurable "build" and "execute" and "compile" actions.  Supports LOTS of languages, I use it as my general GUI text editor

Comment: Surprised nobody mentioned Spyder (https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder/blob/master/README.md). It has plenty of help for beginners and advanced programmers. What I appreciate most is the ability to visualize variables and their content, even for complex data structures.